# What does the ampersand (&) mean in a TypeScript type definition?

Tags: types, typescript, ampersand

On line 60359 of [this type definition file](https://github.com/SaschaNaz/DefinitelyTyped/blob/01fc50d96271f22e813b7ad27f55991474b22df4/winrt/winrt-uwp.d.ts), there is the following declaration:

```
type ActivatedEventHandler = (
    ev: Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs 
        & WinRTEvent<any>
) => void;
```

What does the `&` sigil mean in this context?

Comment: Intersection types: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types

Comment: The newer link to Intersection Types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`&` in a type position means *intersection* type.

#### More from typescript docs on Intersection Types:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Citation from the docs linked above:

> Intersection types are closely related to union types, but they are used very differently. An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need. For example, Person & Serializable & Loggable is a type which is all of Person and Serializable and Loggable. That means an object of this type will have all members of all three types.
>
> For example, if you had networking requests with consistent error handling then you could separate out the error handling into it’s own type which is merged with types which correspond to a single response type.

```
interface ErrorHandling {
  success: boolean;
  error?: { message: string };
}

interface ArtworksData {
  artworks: { title: string }[];
}

interface ArtistsData {
  artists: { name: string }[];
}

// These interfaces are composed to have
// consistent error handling, and their own data.

type ArtworksResponse = ArtworksData & ErrorHandling;
type ArtistsResponse = ArtistsData & ErrorHandling;

const handleArtistsResponse = (response: ArtistsResponse) => {
  if (response.error) {
    console.error(response.error.message);
    return;
  }

  console.log(response.artists);
};
```

Comment: Docs moved to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

Comment: Moved again: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Answer (score 53):

### Intersection type in Typescript

- A & in TS in the context of a types means an intersection type.
- It merges all properties of 2 object types together and creates a new type

---

**Example:**

```
type dog = {age: number, woof: Function};
type cat = {age: number, meow: Function};

// Type weird is an intersection of cat and dog
// it needs to have all properties of them combined
type weird = dog & cat;

const weirdAnimal: weird = {age: 2, woof: () => {'woof'}, meow: () => {'meow'}}

interface extaprop {
    color: string
}

type catDog = weird & extaprop; // type now also has added color
const weirdAnimal2: catDog = {age: 2, woof: () => {'woof'}, meow: () => {'meow'}, color: 'red'}


// This is different form a union type
// The type below means either a cat OR a dog
type dogOrCat = dog | cat;
```

Comment: Isn't this technically a `union` and not an `intersection`?

Comment: "Intersection" refers to the resulting _type_, not the operation performed on the properties. An object belonging to both Type A and Type B must have all properties in A (so that it is an instance of A) while also having all the properties of B (so that it is also an instance of B). In other words, an intersection of the types must have the union of each type's properties. Similarly, the union of types will have the intersection of those types' properties.

Comment: this seems similar to `extends` right?

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs It's like multiple inheritance or multiple interface implementation

Answer (score 5):

Simply put,

`&` between two types mean that you can access **all** properties of both types.

Whereas

`|` means that you can **only** access properties that are **common** to both types.

Comment: Is the definition for `|` really correct? Doesn't it rather stand for `either...or` ?

Comment: That is true, however in this case of type coalescing, it behaves in a slightly twisted way