# What does a prefixing "&" mean in a Typescript type definition?

Tags: typescript

From [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jss/css.d.ts):

> export type CSSProperties =   &
>   ObservableProperties  &
>   ObservableProperties;

Every description of ampersand that I can find says that it is an intersection operator.  In which case, what does the first ampersand mean?

References:

- [What does the ampersand (&) mean in a TypeScript type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317625/what-does-the-ampersand-mean-in-a-typescript-type-definition)
- [Official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)
- [Typescript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html#intersection-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leading ampersand is ignored by the current version of the compiler, pretty much in the same way as the last `;` is ignored inside interface declaration:

```
interface a {
    a(): string;
}


type b = & a;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20b%20%3D%20%26%20a%3B%0D%0A) says `type b = a`

The typings linked from the question are (ab)using this feature to have more uniform syntax for intersection types:

```
export type CSSProperties =
    & ObservableProperties<csstype.Properties>
    & ObservableProperties<csstype.PropertiesHyphen>;
```

When written this way, when you remove the first intersection member for example, you can just delete the whole line and you don't have to change anything else.