# Look for help understanding Typescript syntax for a request parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In Typescript using GitHub's octokit, I am calling an octokit method which is looking for parameters

```
 (RequestParameters & Omit<{ owner: string; repo: string; branch: string; }, "baseUrl" | "headers" | "mediaType">) | undefined)
```

I am confused by the notation `RequestParameters & Omit`.

- Does it mean it needs a structure of type RequestParameters with some fields omitted?
- Should I be able to find a type declaration for 'RequestParameters' in the library I include?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That... doesn't look quite right. Can you give a more complete sample or a link to that file in the library or something?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622396/why-use-in-typescript-generic

Answer (score 0):

Given the [type definition of `RequestParameters`](https://github.com/octokit/types.ts/blob/master/src/RequestParameters.ts), I'm pretty sure the correct type would be:

```js
({ owner: string; repo: string; branch: string; } & Omit<RequestParameters, "baseUrl" | "headers" | "mediaType">) | undefined
```

Which would "compute" into the following type:

```js
{
  owner: string
  repo: string
  branch: string
  request?: RequestRequestOptions
  [parameter: string]: unknown
} | undefined
```

(based on the type definitions from [octokit/types.ts v6.25.0](https://github.com/octokit/types.ts))

Otherwise it makes no sense. Can you tell us where you found the type you are referring to?

As for the explanation:

- `&` is used to create [intersection types](https://github.com/ruizb/glossary-typescript#intersection-type):

  ```js
  type Foo = { name: string } & { surname: string } & { age: number }
  // Foo: {name: string, surname: string, age: number }
  ```
- `Omit` is a [mapped type](https://github.com/ruizb/glossary-typescript#mapped-type) used to create a new type, based on an existing one, but with properties *ommitted* on purpose:

  ```js
  type Bar = Omit<{ name: string, surname: string, age: number }, 'surname'>
  // Bar: { name: string, age: number }
  ```

So here we take an existing type `RequestParameters` from the octokit library, we *omit* some of its properties, and we merge this new type with another one (with a *type intersection*) that has the `owner`, `repo` and `branch` properties.

Finally, we create a [union type](https://github.com/ruizb/glossary-typescript#union-type) between the type we created, and `undefined` (to allow the `undefined` value as a valid parameter of the function).