# Typescritp syntax for default export

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.

In this code

```
import { ITokenCache } from './tokens/token-cache';
import { ISession } from './session/session';
import { ISignInWithAuth0 } from './instance';

export default function createDummyBrowserInstance(): ISignInWithAuth0 & { isBrowser: boolean } {
  return {
    isBrowser: true,
    handleLogin: (): Promise<void> => {
      throw new Error('The handleLogin method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    handleLogout: (): Promise<void> => {
      throw new Error('The handleLogout method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    handleCallback: (): Promise<void> => {
      throw new Error('The handleCallback method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    handleProfile: (): Promise<void> => {
      throw new Error('The handleProfile method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    getSession: (): Promise<ISession | null | undefined> => {
      throw new Error('The getSession method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    requireAuthentication: () => (): Promise<void> => {
      throw new Error('The requireAuthentication method can only be used from the server side');
    },
    tokenCache: (): ITokenCache => {
      throw new Error('The tokenCache method can only be used from the server side');
    }
  };
}
```

I am not able to understand the following line.

I understand that it is an default export but don't understand the syntax after function name.

```
export default function createDummyBrowserInstance(): ISignInWithAuth0 & { isBrowser: boolean } {
```

can you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the ampersand (&) mean in a TypeScript type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317625/what-does-the-ampersand-mean-in-a-typescript-type-definition)

Answer (score 0):

This is the return type.

It uses [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types). In this case, it returns an object having the type of ISignInWithAuth0 with an additional boolean attribute.

I recommend you to read / browse the linked documentation.

Comment: The function createDummyBrowserInstance also returns an object. So the finary object that get exported is combination of ISignInWithAuth0 & { isBrowser: boolean }  & object from return.

Comment: It is not. The syntax after the function name and the columns is the return type. The returned object need to respect the return type and is typed as the return type.